# Convert phrases in HTML to links with Python

Tags: python, html, regex, replace

I have content on a website where certain keywords and keyphrases should be linked to other content.  I do not want to manually insert links into the content. What is the best way to do this in Python, preferably without using any DOM libraries?

For example, I have this text:

`...And this can be accomplished with the Awesome Method. Blah blah blah....`

`Key-phrase: awesome method`

This is the desired output:

`...And this can be accomplished with the <a href="/path/to/awesome-method">Awesome Method</a>. Blah blah blah....`

I have a list of such keyphrases and the corresponding URLs. The phrases can appear in any case in the content, but will be all lowercase in the keyphrase definition.

Currently I am using string-find-replace with combinations of the case-changed words. And it is pretty inefficient.

Comment: Depends on the size of the content and the number and size of phrases to match. If you can give a representative example, you'll probably get more useful (efficient etc.) answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
for keyphrase, url in links:
    content = re.sub('(%s)' % keyphrase, r'<a href="%s">\1</a>' % url, content, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

So for instance, in your example you could do

```
import re

content = "...And this can be accomplished with the Awesome Method. Blah blah blah...."
links = [('awesome method', '/path/to/awesome-method')]

for keyphrase, url in links:
    content = re.sub('(%s)' % keyphrase, r'<a href="%s">\1</a>' % url, content, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# content:
# '...And this can be accomplished with the <a href="/path/to/awesome-method">Awesome Method</a>. Blah blah blah....'
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been using a method similar to what @michael-laszlo suggested. This looks much cleaner. I just need to adjust it to match full phrases so that it doesn't replace part of the words/phrases like ```blaawesome method```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the positions in the text and build the new text with basic string operations:

```
import re

text = """And this can be accomplished with the Awesome Method. Blah blah blah"""

keyphrases = [
    ('awesome method', 'http://awesome.com/'),
    ('blah', 'http://blah.com')
  ] 

new_parts = []

pos = 0
while pos < len(text):
  replaced = False
  for phrase, url in keyphrases:
    substring = text[pos:pos+len(phrase)]
    if substring.lower() == phrase.lower():
      new_parts.append('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, substring))
      pos += len(substring)
      replaced = True
      break
  if not replaced:
    new_parts.append(text[pos])
    pos += 1

new_text = ''.join(new_parts)
print(new_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [anchorman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anchorman/) module - to turn your text into hypertext.

```
import anchorman

text = "...And this can be accomplished with the Awesome Method. Blah blah blah...."
links = [{'awesome method': {'value': '/path/to/awesome-method'}}]
markup_format = {
    'tag': 'a',
    'value_key': 'href',
    'attributes': [
        ('class', 'anups')
    ],
    'case_sensitive': False
}

a = anchorman.add(text, links, markup_format=markup_format)
print a
...And this can be accomplished with the <a href="/path/to/awesome-method"
class="anups">Awesome Method</a>. Blah blah blah....
```